# How can I run to be an unpledged elector?

Tags: united-states, voting

I live in Tennessee. I think it would be a hoot to run to be an unpledged elector in 2020. Even if I lost it would still be a hoot.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "unpledged elector".  All electors in the Electoral College are nominally bound to vote for a specific candidate, although laws enforcing that vary from state to state (and have never been tested in court).  That wasn't the original intent of the College, but it's the current reality.

In the various party primaries, there are "[unpledged delegates](https://ballotpedia.org/Unpledged_delegates)", but the rules for them vary from party to party and sometimes state to state and [year to year](https://ballotpedia.org/2016_presidential_nominations:_calendar_and_delegate_rules).

For the Democrats in 2016, the only unpledged delegates were "members of the Democratic National Committee, Democratic members of Congress, Democratic governors, or distinguished party leaders".
For the Republicans in 2016, it very much depended on the state.  In [Tennessee](https://ballotpedia.org/Presidential_election_in_Tennessee,_2016), all delegates were pledged, including the three "bonus" delegates of the state's RNC members.

All-in-all, your best bet to be an unpledged delegate is to get elected as a Democratic Representative in the 2018 election. That will  make you a (probably) unbound superdelegate in the 2020 Democratic primary.